# Adding Linux to a MacBook bro

Tags: macos, kali-linux

So I am trying to install Kali Linux on my mac as a dual but for some reason, the last step is on their documentation [page](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install) did not work for me!

It Asks me to type something similar to this

```
sudo dd if=kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk6 bs=1m
```

the image that I downloaded is `kali-linux-light-2019.1a-armhf.img` which is the latest version provided by their website so the command I am trying to run is this

```
sudo dd if=kali-linux-light-2019.1a-armhf.img of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

But unfortunately, I got this error

> $-bash: sudo dd if=kali-linux-light-2019.1a-armhf.img of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m: No such file or directory

Hence I run my commands on the Desktop directory where the image lives.

Comment: Putting aside that it may be the wrong disk image, and just looking at the dd command you used, (for the sake of you learning about dd), what if you try `ls -l kali-linux-light-2019.1a-armhf.img`   See if it shows anything. If it does then the `if=kali-linux-light-2019.1a-armhf.img`  should not cause a `No such file or directory`   You're unlikely to get a running linux from it but you won't break your laptop irreperably either! And if you want to learn stuff about installing linux then using a macbook pro is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I see several things wrong here.

1. You have downloaded the wrong disk image. The ARMHF image is for ARM systems. I'm frankly not sure why Kali even provides this as a download, as there are very few ARM systems in existence which will boot from a USB storage device.
2. You have somehow managed to mistype the command line in such a way as to make your shell think that the entire command is supposed to be a filename. I'm not sure how you managed to do this; I've been unable to reproduce this error.
3. You are attempting to install a Linux distribution which is intended for experienced Linux users. The issues you are having here suggest that you may be new to the command line in general; I would strongly recommend that you read the Kali documentation page [Should I Use Kali Linux?](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux), and consider installing a different distribution such as Debian or Ubuntu Linux.

   (Note as well that Kali Linux is not designed with hardware compatibility as a major goal. It may not run on your laptop at all.)